# How to make duplicate comparison with MySQL DB information when registering in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I followed the tutorial with Express, MySQL, and JWT.

And I have confirmed that everything works fine and now I want to check for duplicate emails when I sign up.

I registered both the tutorial source code and the code I tried.

I added the code to check for emails when rows> 0 to check for emails when registering, but after checking with Postman, the duplicate emails are still stored in the DB.

**tutorial code**

```
users.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var appData = {
        "error": 1,
        "data": ""
    };
    var userData = {
        "email": req.body.email,
        "password": req.body.password,
    }
    database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            appData["error"] = 1;
            appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', userData, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    appData.error = 0;
                    appData["data"] = "User registered successfully!";
                    res.status(201).json(appData);
                } else {
                    appData["data"] = "Error Occured!";
                    res.status(400).json(appData);
                }
            });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});
```

**Trying Code**

```
    users.post('/register', function(req, res) {

        var appData = {
            "error": 1,
            "data": ""
        };
        var userData = {
            "email": req.body.email,
            "password": req.body.password,
        }

        database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                appData["error"] = 1;
                appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
                res.status(500).json(appData);
            } else {
                connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', userData, function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        if (rows[0].email == email) {
                            appData.error = 1;
                            sppData["data"] = "Email Duplicate Error
"
                        } else {
                            if (!err) {
                                appData.error = 0;
                                appData["data"] = "User registered successfully!";
                                res.status(201).json(appData);
                            } else {
                                appData["data"] = "Error Occured!";
                                res.status(400).json(appData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                connection.release();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Put a `email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE` constraint in your table definition to get started.

Comment: Thank you I had forgotten the way!
However, I would like to write code that pops up console.log when duplicate email requests come in. My current code does not work.

Comment: well you have to query your DB "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?" if there is a single row then the email is already taken.